# Prepared SQL Statement not Valid

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jsp

I can't figure this out and its due in 10 hours. If someone's got pity please help.

Basically I am trying to insert data in an access table called `Appointments`. However I get an incorrect sql syntax error each time. I have gone over many examples of sql and this seems correct and I can't wrap my head around this. Code and Stack Trace below. Error line is stated as line 27 or the statement.executeupdate() line. I am trying to do this in a JSP.

```
<%
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
java.sql.Connection connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dentist", "", "");

String query = "INSERT INTO Appointments(First_Name, Last_Name, Address, Phone_Number, Procedure, Appointment_Date, Health_Insurance, Health_Concerns, Age, Emergency_Contact, Cost) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

statement.setString(1, request.getParameter("First_name"));
statement.setString(2, request.getParameter("Last_Name"));
statement.setString(3, request.getParameter("Address"));
statement.setString(4, request.getParameter("PhoneNumber"));
statement.setString(5, request.getParameter("Procedure"));
statement.setString(6, request.getParameter("Appointment_Date"));
statement.setString(7, request.getParameter("Health_Insurance"));
statement.setString(8, request.getParameter("Health_Concerns"));
statement.setString(9, request.getParameter("Age"));
statement.setString(10, request.getParameter("Emergency_Contact"));
statement.setString(11, request.getParameter("Cost"));

statement.executeUpdate(query);
connection.close();
response.sendRedirect("ShowData.jsp");
%>
```

Stack trace:

> Dec 16, 2015 7:38:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.    at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)  at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
>     at
>   sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.FinalProject.ProcessInsert_jsp._jspService(ProcessInsert_jsp.java:80)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:856)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:565)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1509)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Having all this code in a scriptlet is generally not recommended. Think JSTL, EL, servlets...

Answer (score 3):

The query is already defined for the `PreparedStatement`. Replace

```
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

with

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @TyGuy2525, let us know if this solved it, and try to clean up the server tags you have listed under the question (ie: mysql and sql-server). The few references I have looked at mention  "Access Database using JDBC-ODBC bridge"